# Is the modal dialog in google app script editable?

Tags: html, google-apps-script, modal-dialog, showmodaldialog

I'm displaying some html with the .showModalDialog function. I'd want to change some of the properties of this modal dialog, like removing the title and changing the padding, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some limited changes that can be made, such as setWidth() & setHeight(). There's no option to set padding or make advanced changes such as that.